# Relaciones de 1 a N en DataTables y Laravel 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

tengo un problema. Estoy relacionando dos tablas de 1 a N y lo quiero ver reflejado en una lista en la vista en Laravel. Me salen los datos de la primera tabla (usuarios) pero no de la segunda tabla (roles).

**DataTables:**

```
var Tabla = $('#Tabla').DataTable({
columns: [
          {data: 'Id', name: 'Id'},
          {data: 'Nombre', name: 'Nombre'},
          {data: 'Apellido', name: 'Apellido'},
          {data: 'roles.Nombre', name: 'roles.Nombre'},
          {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false}
        ]
});
```

**Controlador Usuario:**

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        // Datatables
        if($request->ajax()){
            $data = Usuario::with('roles')->get();
            
            return DataTables::of($data)
                    ->addColumn('action', function($data){
                      $boton = '<button type="button" name="edit" id="'.$data->id.'" class="btn-editar btn btn-primary btn-sm">Editar</button>';
                      $boton .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="button" name="eliminar" id="'.$data->id.'" class="btn-eliminar btn btn-danger btn-sm">Eliminar</button>';
                      return $boton;
                    })->rawColumns(['action'])->make(true);
          }

        return view('Sistema.Modulos.Usuarios.index');
    }
```

**Modelo Usuario:**

```
class Usuario extends Model
{
public function roles()
    {
      return $this->hasMany(Role::class, 'Id', 'Id');
    }
}
```

**Modelo Role:**

```
class Role extends Model
{
    public function usuarios()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo(Usuarios::class);
    }
}
```

**Vista:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver ahí en la imagen, me sale los datos de la **tabla (usuarios)** pero no me sale de la **tabla (roles)**. No se si esta mal relacionado en los modelos o en DataTables. Les agradecería su ayuda.

**Datos en JSON:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Primero publicá el detalle de las 2 tablas (usuarios y roles) así vemos como se llaman las columnas. Segundo, en el modelo Role estás llamando a `Usuarios::class`, pero por lo que se ve, tu modelo se llama `Usuario`, en singular, sin la `s`.

Answer (score 1):

normalmente un usuario puede tener varios roles y un rol puede aplicar a varios usuarios, en ese caso la relación debería ser many to many.

Otro comentario:

```
class Usuario extends Model
{
public function roles()
    {
      return $this->hasMany(Role::class, 'Id', 'Id');
    }
}
```

No puede ser Id y Id, una es la clave foránea y otra la local.

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Role', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```

Habría que agregar una tercer tabla, según la documentación con este formato:

```
users
    id - integer
    name - string

roles
    id - integer
    name - string

role_user
    user_id - integer
    role_id - integer
```

El model de usuario tendría esta función:

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
}
```

Luego para acceder a los roles de un usuario es algo así:

```
$user = App\User::find(1);

foreach ($user->roles as $role) {
    //
}
```

Y más detalle en la documentación oficial:

[Eloquent: Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Comment: Si, tienes razón no me habia dado cuenta de que tenia el Usuario en plural en el modelo Roles, buena observacion, ya lo corregí. En el segundo punto que añades es que yo no estoy siguiendo la convención de Laravel por eso tengo Id, Id para ambas tablas (usuario, roles) como llave primaria. También corregiré la relación a relación debería ser many to many. ya que tiene lógica lo que planteas, un USUARIO puede tener varios ROLES.

Answer (score 1):

OK, ya resolví el problema. En DataTables no le habia colocado el `[]` en *data:roles*. Ahora si me aparecen todos los datos.

**DataTables:**

```
columns: [
          {data: 'Id', name: 'Id', className: "text-left"},
          {data: 'Nombre', name: 'Nombre', className: "text-left"},
          {data: 'Apellido', name: 'Apellido', className: "text-left"},
          {data: 'roles[].Nombre', name: 'roles.Nombre', className: "text-left"},
          {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false}
        ],
```